# How to create a MEL filter bank using Marsyas?

Tags: c++, audio, filter, mel

I am developing an application using the Marsyas-library.

I added some MarSystems to a "Series"-MarSystem. Now I want to *add a MEL or BARK **filter bank*** (band-pass filter) to calculate the energy of each band afterwards. I would use a "**TriangularFilterBank**" to da this but how do I setup a MEL filter bank using this MarSystem properly?

After that I want to *access the pocessed data of **of each** band **of two** consecutive frames **at once***. How do you do that?

The code of the described scenario:

```
Marsyas::MarSystem *net = manager.create("Series", "net");
net->addMarSystem(manager.create("SoundFileSource","src"));

// ... 

net->addMarSystem(manager.create("Windowing", "ham")); // creates "frames"
net->addMarSystem(manager.create("Spectrum", "spec"));
net->addMarSystem(manager.create("PowerSpectrum", "powerSpec"));

// How to add a mel filter band here? <---

net->addMarSystem(manager.create("Energy", "en"));

// ...  

while (net->getctrl("SoundFileSource/src/mrs_bool/hasData")->to<Marsyas::mrs_bool>()) 
{
    // This processes one frame at a time at the moment:
    net->tick(); 
    Marsyas::mrs_realvec vec = net->getctrl("mrs_realvec/processedData")->to<Marsyas::mrs_realvec>(); 

    // How can I access the pocessed data of EACH band of WTO consecutive 
    // frames at ONCE here? <--    -

}
```

1.) How do I add a mel filter band to the system?

2.) How can I access the pocessed data of each band of two consecutive windows at once?